# How to copy the first row value to rest values using Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

i am using Angular8 in my project, here, when i click on `Match First Row` button, then the values in first row to be copied to all rows, `so all the checkboxes, dropdown and Input fields to be copied`. But if the first row is selected with `email delivery method` and 2nd row as `Fax Delivery Method` and inputed with proper format, and when i click on `Match First Row` button, then except 2nd row, all rows are filled with recipient value, but the row which i had given fax number doesnt get filled with the first row value. I am not able to fix this issue, any help.

TS:

```
 checkAll(ev) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.exampleForm.get("printList");
    const baseValue = (control.controls[0] as any).getRawValue();
    control.controls.forEach((x, i) => {
      x.get("electronics").setValue(baseValue.electronics);
      x.get("mail").setValue(baseValue.mail);
      x.get("deliveryMethodId").setValue(baseValue.deliveryMethodId);
      x.get("recipients").setValue(baseValue.recipients);
    });
    if (baseValue.electronics) {
      control.controls.forEach((x, i) => {
        x.get("deliveryMethodId").enable();
        x.get("recipients").enable();
      });
    } else {
      control.controls.forEach((x, i) => {
        x.get("deliveryMethodId").disable();
        x.get("recipients").disable();
        x.get("deliveryMethodId").setValue(null);
        x.get("recipients").setValue(null);
      });
    }
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-uszysd)

Answer (score 0):

See below approach

1. Get value of the 1st item
2. Foreach input, if the input is touched and valid, ignore otherwise set its value to the value we got in the 1st item.
3. Validations will be updated by the the subscription in the `ngOnInit`

```
  checkAll() {
    const value = this.printListControl.at(0).value;
    this.printListControl.controls.forEach(control => {
      if (!(control.valid && control.touched)) {
        control.patchValue(value);
      }
    });
  }
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-dbhpzq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but here in the 2nd row i have added fax dropdown and gave 10 numbers, but when i clicked on button, except fax rest things got changed, i need all rows to get same value as first row

Comment: Is this what you expect? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-6fzlsn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-17phut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i have made data, here 1st row is having email as dropdown so email format has been given, 2nd row is having fax in dropdown and fax format is given, now when i click on button, i must get all 4 rows to have same value as 1st row, but 2nd row 'recipient" is empty instead of email id

Comment: Sorry, i updated my question, here in this all checkboxes,dropdown and input field to be filled as 1st row, but if any input from 2nd to 4th is filled with fax dropdown and fax input, then if i make default, that fax input which had before will become empty and rest fields will get filled with email, hope i need to reset mask value, but not getting